# call matSortChange on Mat Table Data Load

Tags: angular, angular-material

Generally matSortChange is called on click of table header.is there any way to trigger matSortChange on Table data load for a particular column.

```
<table matSort (matSortChange)="sortData($event)">
  <tr>
    <th mat-sort-header="name">Dessert (100g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="calories">Calories</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="fat">Fat (g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="carbs">Carbs (g)</th>
    <th mat-sort-header="protein">Protein (g)</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

call sortData($event) on table data load

```
  sortData(sort: Sort) {
    // call this function as soon as table data is loaded so that the data is already sorted
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define on the `mat-table` two properties `matSortActive` and `matSortDirection` which will define the initial sorting

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort (matSortChange)="announceSortChange($event)"
       class="mat-elevation-z8" matSortActive="name" matSortDirection="asc">
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/z1pn93?file=src%2Fexample%2Ftable-sorting-example.css,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-sorting-example.ts,src%2Fexample%2Ftable-sorting-example.html)